# Use an environment variable to point to an "Open With" program

Tags: windows, windows-registry, environment-variables, file-association

I have Windows Vista, but I guess this pertains to other versions as well.
I want to set a program to be used in the Open With context menu. Now I want that the path to the .exe contain an environment variable. In that way, I can move the location of my app, change the corresponding environment variable, and everything works fine.

The problem has three components:

1. The value of the key in

   ```
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\myapp.exe\shell\open\command
   ```

   e.g., `"C:\myapp\myapp.exe" "%1"`, is hardcoded, and the type is `REG_SZ`.
   I would need it to be of type `REG_EXPAND_SZ`, e.g., `"%MYAPPSDIR%\myapp.exe" "%1"`.
   This is typical for built-in programs, e.g., `%SystemRoot%\system32\NOTEPAD.EXE %1`.
2. The type of key cannot be changed, so what was born as `REG_SZ`, so it lives.
3. It appears that I cannot ["regenerate" the variable as `REG_EXPAND_SZ`](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/how-can-i-edit-the-value-type-of-a-registry-key.2422579/).

Is there any chance of doing what I mean?

There is also a bonus question, [How to receive a parameter in a batch file](https://superuser.com/q/932408/245595).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
reg add "HKCR\Applications\myapp.exe\shell\open\command" /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "\"^%MYAPPSDIR^%\myapp.exe\" \"^%1\"" /f
```

Note:

- to avoid expanding `%MYAPPSDIR%` by command line interpreter, `%` percent character should be escaped by the standard `CLI` escape character (`^` caret): `^%MYAPPSDIR^%`;
- to include a quote mark `"` in the data, prefix it with the `reg` escape character (`\` backslash). E.g. `\"` here is a quote as the `REG` command will interpret `\` as an escape for the character that immediately follows it.

An example (`copy&paste` from my *administrator* command line):

```
C:\Windows\system32>reg query "HKCR\Applications\mspaint.exe\shell\edit\command" /ve

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\mspaint.exe\shell\edit\command
    (Default)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    "%systemroot%\system32\mspaint.exe" "%1"

C:\Windows\system32>reg add "HKCR\Applications\mspaint.exe\shell\edit\command" /ve /t
 REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "\"^%systemroot^%\system32\mspaint.exe\" \"^%1\"" /f
The operation completed successfully.

C:\Windows\system32>reg query "HKCR\Applications\mspaint.exe\shell\edit\command" /ve

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\mspaint.exe\shell\edit\command
    (Default)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    "%systemroot%\system32\mspaint.exe" "%1"
```

Comment: Excellent! Please see bonus question http://superuser.com/q/932408/245595